# Async script in React/Next js not running/showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, next.js

I'm trying to add Amazon Native Shopping ads to my website, but the ad never shows up.
Their code looks like this:

```
<div id="amzn-assoc-ad-944106c8-19e7-4323-aa3f-71c0cef0998b"></div>
<script async src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=944106c8-19e7-4323-aa3f-71c0cef0998b"></script>
```

So far I've tried both adding the script with the Nextjs `<Script>`, adding the `<script>` inside the Nextjs `<Head>`, as well as creating the script in a useEffect hook like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src =
      "//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=944106c8-19e7-4323-aa3f-71c0cef0998b";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);
```

They also offer a synchronous script, but this one always shows at the bottom of the page.

Anyone